# python multiprocessing Process is killed by http request if ipdb is imported

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multiprocessing, ipdb

It seems simply importing `ipdb` when making an http request wrapped in a `multiprocessing Process` instance causes the program to exit with no errors or messages.

The following script behaves very strangely:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import requests
import ipdb

def spawn():

    print("before")
    r = requests.get("http://wtfismyip.com")
    print("after")

Process(target=spawn).start()
```

If you run this in terminal the output is simply `before` and you are back at your prompt. If you comment out `import ipdb` everything is fine and the request is successfully made.

- Storing the `Process` instance in a variable and calling `join()` after `start()` didn't make a difference.
- This happens in both Python 2.7.10 and 3.5.0.
- It does **not** happen with the traditional `pdb`.
- Other people [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453152/python-multiprocessing-and-requests) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766419/python-child-process-silently-crashes-when-issuing-an-http-request) have also had this issue. In the former I am not sure if importing `ipdb` was the cause. In the latter it appeared to be an package/python version upgrade issue, but I checked that my `iPython` and `ipdb` are the current latest (4.0.0 and 0.8.1).

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: I could not recreate this with Python 2.7.9 and IPython 2.3.0 on Linux. What OS are you on?

Comment: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. Note that I saw this on 2.7.10 and 3.5.0, maybe something changed in 2.7.9 -> 2.7.10 that is causing this. No clue. I'm using iPython 4.0.0.

Comment: I cannot explain, but you could find a workaround by only importing ipdb when you actually need it: `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`. Keeping debug-related statements in the same place will make things easier when you'll need to remove them before pushing to production (if you ever do)

Comment: Thanks or your comment, I get that. I'd like to understand why, or help raise attention to a bug if there is one in one of the packages.

Comment: @ministry I am facing something similar in Python 2.7.12 / ipdb 0.11 on Ubuntu 16.04.4 as well. Not sure what is causing this. Have you figured out the reason for this? Please let me know.

Comment: @Phani no sorry, I have not looked at this for a while.